# NullPointerException thrown in java synchronised method using sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets, nullpointerexception, synchronized

I have an android app written in java.

The app basically connects to a device which sends the app messages. The app waits for the messages to come in and then reports them, before processing each message.

I have a **Connection** class and a **Listener** class.

The **Connection** class is started via the constructor, which sets up the **Listener** class to listen for messages coming in from the device.

When a message comes in, the Listener sends the message to a method in the Connection class, **reportMessage()**. This is where the message is processed.

The **Listener** class is on a separate thread.

The code is shown below.

```
public class Connection 
{
    private String response;
    private String newResponse;

    private DataInputStream reader;

    private DataOutputStream writer; 

    private Socket socket;

    private boolean keepListening;

    private Listener listener;

    public Connection (String _ipAddress, int portNumber)
    {
        newResponse = "";

        try 
        {
            socket = new Socket(_ipAddress, _port);   //Connect to the server and its socket

            writer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); //Connect to the server to receive and send messages

            reader = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            listener = new Listener(reader, this); //Create a new listener for the client

            new Thread(listener).start(); //Set the listener off running
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            ...
        } 
    }

    public synchronized void reportMessage(String message)
    {
        try
        {
            if("".equals(newResponse))
            {
                newResponse = new String();
            }

            newResponse = newResponse + message;

            System.out.println("Message Received: " + newResponse);

            processMessage(); //Process the message
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            response = e.getCause().toString();
        }
    }
}

public class Listener implements Runnable 
{
    private DataInputStream reader = null;

    private boolean keepListening;

    private String serverMessage;

    private Connection connection;

    public Listener (DataInputStream inFromServer, Connection connection)
    {
        reader = inFromServer;
                               //Get the client connection's message transfer
        keepListening = true;

        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while (keepListening)
        {
            try
            {
                if (reader.available() > 0)
                {
                    byte[] readInData = new byte[reader.available()];  //Initialise the array

                    reader.read (readInData);  //Read in the data

                    serverMessage = Utils.byteToString(readInData);

                    connection.reportMessage(serverMessage);   //Report the message
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error reading." + e.getLocalizedMessage().toString());

                keepListening = false;
            }

            keepListening = connection.getKeepListening();
        }
    }
}
```

This works well for a time, then sometimes I receive an error which crashes the program.

When running in debug mode, I get a **NullPointerException** thrown on whatever is the first line of **reportMessage()** in the **Connection** class.

The program is suspended on whatever line is the first line, whether it is a **System.out.println** or a line of actual code.

And the error doesn't get caught by the try and catch. It crashes the program and there is no handling of the error even though it occurs in the try and catch.

This leads me to believe the error is not being thrown by anything in the **reportMessage()** method. If this is the case, then perhaps the error is being thrown in the Listener class **.run()**.

However, I cannot see where any **NullPointerException** can be thrown from, as I have tried to make all the checks and when it is thrown, it is thrown when there are messages being sent.

The debugger says "An exception stack trace is not available".

The LogCat says:

```
  08-21 10:35:57.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1118): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-12
  08-21 10:35:57.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1118): java.lang.NullPointerException
  08-21 10:35:57.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1118):atCom.que.wifiaudio.Connection.reportMessage(Connection.java:339)
  08-21 10:35:57.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1118):   at com.que.wifiaudio.Listener.reportIncomingMessage(Listener.java:93)
  08-21 10:35:57.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1118):   at com.que.wifiaudio.Listener.run(Listener.java:67)

  08-21 10:35:57.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1118):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1102)
```

Can anyone help me?

I need to know what is throwing the NullPointerException and how to stop it!

EDIT: Thanks to a lot of help, it now turns out it is the Exception I am catching and trying to get the cause of which is null. Still trying to work out where it is coming from though!

Comment: what is exactly the 339th line of Connection.java?

Comment: does not make sense. the stacktrace would contain the line in the processMessage.

Comment: you are not supposed to use System.out in android. Use Log.d(String, String) instead. You'll have more info. Also, what is there in processMessage ?

Comment: Thanks about the Log, I didn't know. And I know the error message doesn't make sense - it doesn't appear to be throwing on a specific line, just the top line of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that an exception is thrown in processMessage, caught in the catch bellow it, but the getCause is null.

1/ Try to log the exception before handling it

2/ Look in processMessage, there should be an exception thrown.

Comment: You are indeed correct. It seems it is being thrown an exception with cause null and the program is suspending because the program is in the catch area of the program and therefore can't be caught. Thanks for pointing this out. Do you have any idea why an Exception would have a null cause?

Comment: And can you suggest a way to log the exception without throwing a null error?

Comment: e.printstacktrace could help. e.getMessage, too

Comment: Thanks very much. It was a String.substring that was throwing an exception. I'd have never have found that! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
  if((newResponse==null) || ("".equals(newResponse))
```

Or use brilliant guava's:

```
  if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(newResponse))
```

Comment: in android, one would rather use TextUtils.isEmpty(), which does the same without external library

Comment: Thanks, I've added that into the code (TextUtils.isEmpty()). It doesn't seem to be the cause of the problem. The problem seems to be I'm trying to get the cause of an exception that has null cause.

Answer (score 0):

`message` or `newResponse` may be null because it will get converted to `message.toString()` and `newResponse.toString()` by compiler.

Add condition for null check :

```
if(message != null && newResponse!=null) {
   newResponse = newResponse + message;
} else {
   // throw exception ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
if("".equals(newResponse))
```

Use this:

```
if(newResponse==null)
```

An empty string is not the same as a `null` object; therefore, in cases when `newResonse` is `null`, it won't be initialized with a proper `String` object, and you wind up with the NPE.

Answer (score 0):

One thing which I see is that in reportMessage(), you are checking whether newResponse is an empty string - however you have not initialized it before, so it is most likely null. Probably what you want is

```
if(newResponse == null) {
    newResponse = new String();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, newResponse is initialised earlier on: I've edited the post