# Parameter-free call to method in same class yields NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, multithreading, nullpointerexception, synchronized

I've seen my fair share of weird errors but this time, I'm completely stumped. I'm getting a NullPointerException when trying to call a method in the same class.

First off, some of the code. Let's start with the offending line. The method is, of course, longer than this but this is the start of it and all that is relevant:

```
protected synchronized void checkTransfers() {
    if (isPaused())
        return;
}
```

`isPaused` is a simple getter method:

```
protected boolean isPaused() {
    return paused.get();
}
```

And for completeness' sake:

```
protected AtomicBoolean paused = new AtomicBoolean(false);
```

Now the problem is that about 50% of the time this code is run, it simply throws a NullPointerException on the `if (isPaused())` line, which makes no sense to me. The `checkTransfers()` method is in the same class as `isPaused()`. My colleague tried helping me out by mentioning that the problem could be in the multithreading that is involved if for instance another thread has gotten CPU time and deleted its reference to the object, but the object should never lose its reference anywhere in my code. Also: `this` is still properly defined once the NPE triggers.

The stacktrace is as follows:

> main@830013674640" prio=5 runnable
>     java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>       at com.omines.android.communicationmanager.CommunicationManager.checkTransfers(CommunicationManager.java:125)
>       at com.omines.android.communicationmanager.DownloadTask.onPostExecute(DownloadTask.java:105)
>       at com.omines.android.communicationmanager.DownloadTask.onPostExecute(DownloadTask.java:20)
>       at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
>       at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
>       at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java:-1)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java:-1)

Line 125 in `checkTransfers()` is the if statement above.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause behaviour like this?

Comment: I just found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070118/nullpointerexception-thrown-in-java-synchronised-method-using-sockets) question which seems to be related. Will try and work that out first.

Comment: Have you tried making 'paused' final?

Comment: I have now, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I cannot imagine that it is the 'paused' instance then, that's null. Is there some other stuff on the same line, that you considered irrelevant and left out here? Can you give a stacktrace?

Comment: No, the only part of the method that I left out was stuff **after** the offending if statement.

  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   at com.omines.android.communicationmanager.CommunicationManager.checkTransfers(CommunicationManager.java:125)
   at com.omines.android.communicationmanager.DownloadTask.onPostExecute(DownloadTask.java:105)
   at com.omines.android.communicationmanager.DownloadTask.onPostExecute(DownloadTask.java:20)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
   at ...

(Left out most of the OS stuff.)

Comment: Try synchronizing isPaused().

Comment: This gives the same result, sadly. But thanks!

Comment: I already solved the issue (see below) but I added a full stacktrace into the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, it took some wicked debugging, but I seem to have found the issue. Posting it in case it can help someone else later.

First, you'll need to know a bit more about my method. This is the full one:

```
protected synchronized void checkTransfers() {
    if (isPaused())
        return;
    while (transferQueue.peek() != null && (transferQueue.peek().priority == PRIORITY_URGENT ||
            (transferSemaphore.availablePermits() > maxConcurrentTransfers)))
    {
        CommunicationTask ct = transferQueue.poll();
        if (ct != null)
        {
            if (ct instanceof DownloadTask)
                currentlyDownloading.add((DownloadTask)ct);
            ct.execute();
        }
    }
}
```

I found out that it would not throw the exception right at the start of the method. As it turns out, prior to the exception it would run through the entire method once, then instead of exiting it, the debugger would jump to the first line of the method and throw a NullPointerException.

With something in hand to work with, I found out that this happened whenever not a DownloadTask but an UploadTask got executed. As it turned out, all my DownloadTasks knew their calling Activity so that they could show progress dialogs, but the UploadTask was always passed `null` instead of a reference to the caller. In an older version of the code this was fine, but after some recent changes, apparently it became a problem.

I'm still not sure why I didn't just get an exception whenever my task tried to access the non-existent reference to its calling activity, but apparently it's normal behaviour to trigger an exception in a seemingly unrelated bit of code.

Thanks for taking the time to read my question and trying to help. I hope at least my answer helps someone else.